# Pacemaker: stopping pacemaker doesn't always move resources to other node

Tags: cluster, sles, pacemaker

I have created a 2 node cluster on sles12. Following is the configuration -

```
    msnode1:~ # crm --version
    crm 3.0.0

    msnode1:~ #  corosync -v
    Corosync Cluster Engine, version '2.3.6'
    Copyright (c) 2006-2009 Red Hat, Inc.

msnode1:~ # crm config show
node 1: msnode1
node 2: msnode2
primitive mspersonal systemd:mspersonal \
        op monitor interval=30s
primitive virtip IPaddr \
        params ip=10.243.109.103 cidr_netmask=21 \
        op monitor interval=30s
location cli-prefer-virtip virtip role=Started inf: msnode1
colocation msconstraint inf: virtip mspersonal
order msorder Mandatory: virtip mspersonal
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
        have-watchdog=false \
        dc-version=1.1.16-4.8-77ea74d \
        cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
        cluster-name=mscluster \
        stonith-enabled=false \
        placement-strategy=balanced \
        help \
        list \
        last-lrm-refresh=1561341732
rsc_defaults rsc-options: \
        resource-stickiness=100 \
        migration-threshold=2
op_defaults op-options: \
        timeout=600 \
        record-pending=true

msnode1:~ # crm status
Stack: corosync
Current DC: msnode1 (version 1.1.16-4.8-77ea74d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Jun 25 17:43:44 2019
Last change: Tue Jun 25 17:38:21 2019 by hacluster via cibadmin on msnode1

2 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ msnode1 msnode2 ]

Full list of resources:

 virtip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr):        Started msnode1
 mspersonal     (systemd:mspersonal):   Started msnode1
```

When I shut off the cluster on node1 (or reboot node1), the resources started on msnode2, but then they immediately turned off and situation changes as -

```
msnode1:~ # systemctl stop pacemaker
msnode2:~ # crm status
Stack: corosync
Current DC: msnode2 (version 1.1.16-4.8-77ea74d) - partition WITHOUT quorum
Last updated: Tue Jun 25 17:44:26 2019
Last change: Tue Jun 25 17:38:20 2019 by hacluster via cibadmin on msnode1

2 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ msnode2 ]
OFFLINE: [ msnode1 ]

Full list of resources:

 virtip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr):        Stopped
 mspersonal     (systemd:mspersonal):   Stopped
```

When I restart the pacemaker service on msnode1, the resources starts back on msnode1 --

```
msnode1:~ # systemctl start pacemaker
msnode1:~ # crm status
Stack: corosync
Current DC: msnode2 (version 1.1.16-4.8-77ea74d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Jun 25 17:46:09 2019
Last change: Tue Jun 25 17:38:20 2019 by hacluster via cibadmin on msnode1

2 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ msnode1 msnode2 ]

Full list of resources:

 virtip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr):        Started msnode1
 mspersonal     (systemd:mspersonal):   Started msnode1
```

But when I redo the same exercise, the resources actually start on msnode2 -

```
msnode1:~ # systemctl stop pacemaker
msnode2:~ # crm status
Stack: corosync
Current DC: msnode2 (version 1.1.16-4.8-77ea74d) - partition WITHOUT quorum
Last updated: Tue Jun 25 17:47:00 2019
Last change: Tue Jun 25 17:38:20 2019 by hacluster via cibadmin on msnode1

2 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ msnode2 ]
OFFLINE: [ msnode1 ]

Full list of resources:

 virtip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr):        Started msnode2
 mspersonal     (systemd:mspersonal):   Started msnode2
```

But when I start pacemaker again on msnode1, the resources move back to msnode1, which I didn't expect because of stickiness set to 100.

I am not able to catch what I am missing in this cluster configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot say why the first try had the resources stopped altogether without logs or more information. The second exercise behaved how I would have expected given the location constraints below.

```
location cli-prefer-virtip virtip role=Started inf: msnode1
```

This location constraint has an infinity score which is going to far outweigh your stickiness score of 200. If you were to remove this location constraint and try the test again I suspect it will behave in the desired way.